# hbase(main):007:0> create 'test', 'data' Error

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I installed and configured hbase-0.94.2, while Connecting to the running instance of HBase using the hbase shell command and trying to create a table named test with a single  column family named data :
`hbase(main):007:0> create 'test', 'data'`the shell displays an error and a stack trace .
what should I do to resolve this.
I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=--lax6MCs6k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I resolved this problem by restarting Hbase
   step1:

```
$cd /usr/local/hbase/bin
```

step2:

```
$./start-hbase.sh
localhost: zookeeper running as process 3669. Stop it first.
master running as process 3783. Stop it first.
localhost: regionserver running as process 3926. Stop it first.
```

step3:

```
   $kill 3669
   $kill 3783
   $kill 3926
```

step4:

```
./start-hbase.sh
```

step5:
verify if it works : `http://localhost:60010/`

Answer (score 0):

posting the stacktrace you will be useful for us to help you out.

also, 0.94.2 is old you should consider moving to a 0.98.x release.

here are my easy step to start using hbase:

- $ wget https://archive.apache.org/dist/hbase/hbase-0.98.0/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz
- $ tar xzvf hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2-bin.tar.gz
- $ export HBASE_HOME=`pwd`/hbase-0.98.0-hadoop2
- $ export PATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
- $ start-hbase.sh

Now hbase is up and running and you can start using the shell

- $ hbase shell